# Python: Devolver una lista con las keys de un dict ordenada en base a una de las propiedades del dict

Tags: python, lista, diccionarios

Es dificil de explicar con palabras así que lo muestro con un ejemplo:

Tengo este diccionario:

```
{
  "gato": {"prioridad": 3, "otros_attrs": "otros"},
  "perro": {"prioridad": 1, "otros_attrs": "otros"},
  "pajaro": {"prioridad": 4, "otros_attrs": "otros"},
  "grillo": {"prioridad": 0, "otros_attrs": "otros"},
  "delfin": {"prioridad": 3, "otros_attrs": "otros"},
  "pez": {"prioridad": 2, "otros_attrs": "otros"}
}
```

Necesito obtener una lista ordenada de las keys del diccionario padre en base a la prioridad en orden creciente. O sea que necesitaría obtener:

```
output = ["grillo", "perro", "pez", "gato", "delfin", "pajaro"]
```

"gato" y "delfin" podrían estar invertidos ya que tienen la misma prioridad

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDITADO**: la respuesta que había dado no era correcta, así que la he recortado

---

La función `sorted()` tiene un argumento para indicar la clave de ordenación. Como argumento, se pasa una función de un sólo argumento que devuelva la clave de cada elemento del iterable.

Así pues, la ordenación que pides sería algo así:

`python output = sorted(dic.keys(), key=lambda x: dic[x]["prioridad"])`

Comment: Puedes poner `dic` en vez de `dic.keys()`.

Comment: Supongo que es cuestión de gustos. Si prefiero `dic.keys()` es por 1) tener más significado semántico, 2) `iter(dic)` acaba siendo una llamada a `iter(dic.keys())` y 3), del zen de python, _"Explícito es mejor que implícito"_.

Comment: Tienes razón, la verdad es que a la hora de releer el código se entiende mejor con `dic.keys()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
animales = {
  "gato": {"prioridad": 3, "otros_attrs": "otros"},
  "perro": {"prioridad": 1, "otros_attrs": "otros"},
  "pajaro": {"prioridad": 4, "otros_attrs": "otros"},
  "grillo": {"prioridad": 0, "otros_attrs": "otros"},
  "delfin": {"prioridad": 3, "otros_attrs": "otros"},
  "pez": {"prioridad": 2, "otros_attrs": "otros"}
}
```

Lo primero es recorrer el diccionario creando una lista de tuplas (animal, prioridad)

```
lista = []
for animal, value in animales.items():
    prioridad = value["prioridad"]
    lista.append((animal, prioridad))
print(lista)
```

produce:

```
[('gato', 3), ('perro', 1), ('pajaro', 4), ('grillo', 0), ('delfin', 3), ('pez', 2)]
```

Ahora queremos ordenar las tuplas de acuerdo con su segundo elemento

```
lista.sort(key = lambda tupla : tupla[1])
print(lista)
```

produce

```
[('grillo', 0), ('perro', 1), ('pez', 2), ('gato', 3), ('delfin', 3), ('pajaro', 4)]
```

Y extraemos los nombres con compresión de listas:

```
final = [tupla[0] for tupla in lista]
print(final)

['grillo', 'perro', 'pez', 'gato', 'delfin', 'pajaro']
```